# bottle.py raising ValueError('I/O operation on closed file',) with file.save()

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

For my current project, I am using python bottle. At the moment, I am trying to save a file that the user uploads in a form, but it's raising the error shown above. I followed the docs in the best way I could, but no matter what I have tried it gave this error.

Here is the function:

```
def uploadFile(file, isPublic, userId, cu, dirId=-1):
    """Takes a bottle FileUpload instance as an argument and adds it to storage/media as well as adds its 
    info to the database. cu should be the db cursor. isPublic should be a bool. userId should be the 
    uploaders id. dirId is the directory ID and defaults to -1."""
    fakeName = file.filename
    extension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
    cu.execute("SELECT * FROM files WHERE fileId=(SELECT MAX(fileId) FROM files)")
    newId = cu.fetchone()
    if newId==None:
        newId = 0
    else:
        newId = newId[1]
    if debugMode:
        print(f"newId {newId}") 
    fileName = f"userfile-{newId}-{userId}.{extension}"
    file.save(vdata["m_folder"] + "/" + fileName)
    cu.execute("INSERT INTO files VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    (userId, newId, dirId, fakeName, fileName, isPublic))
    cu.connection.commit()
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: As mentioned in the error "I/O operation on closed file", you are trying to use file object which is closed. Use with statement, which open the file object and then closes it.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile are you sure? I've found that the python standard library does not follow this convention half the time.

Comment: @Brendon It's what [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends, although consistency always comes first. Do you have any particular areas of the standard library in mind?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm sorry to say that I don't have any areas in mind at the moment, but I remember reading through the docs and adapting the style I use here because I found it to be the easiest to read, but I'll keep in mind to use `lower_case_with_underscores` for my next project.

Comment: @Brendon Can you share a bit more of your program? In particular, is that function taking a file object as a parameter?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the `file` parameter is a bottle.py FileUpload object; it seems that the error lies within the FileUpload objects' internal file object not being open by the time `file.save` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example of uploading files using Bottle framework**

I am not sure if you need this answer anymore but I like to include it for future readers. Here is a complete example of *How to upload file using bottle framework*

Directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── uploaded_files
└── views
    └── file_upload.tpl
```

`app.py`:

```
import os
from bottle import Bottle, run, request, template

app = Bottle()

def handle_file_upload(upload):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
    if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg'):
        return 'File extension not allowed.'

    save_path = "uploaded_files"
    upload.save(save_path) # appends upload.filename automatically
    return 'OK'

@app.route('/')
def file_upload():
    return template('file_upload')

@app.route('/upload', method='POST')
def do_upload():
    category   = request.forms.get('category')
    upload     = request.files.get('upload')
    return handle_file_upload(upload)

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

`views/file_upload.tpl`:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Category:      <input type="text" name="category" />
  Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
```

**Output:**

Screenshot after uploading a valid file:

[image: screenshot after uploading a valid file]

**Probable problem in the mentioned case:**

There is a chance that the following code block may raise the exception:

```
fileName = f"userfile-{newId}-{userId}.{extension}"
file.save(vdata["m_folder"] + "/" + fileName)
```

Please check the values of each variables: `newId`, `userId`, `extension`, `vdata["m_folder"]`

Also you can replace `"/"` with `os.sep` or `os.path.sep`.

As @AlexanderCécile mentioned in comment, passing the file object to external method may also cause the problem. You may rename the variable name `file` to something else, but I don't think it will fix the problem at all.

**Update**

I have updated the code. Now I am sending the file object to another method rather than the routing function but the code still works perfectly.

**Reference:**

1. [bottle official docs for file uploading](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#file-uploads)

Comment: This is a very nice answer, and I do appreciate it; I would, however, like to note that from my routing function, I call a separate function (as shown in my question).

Comment: @Brendon, I have updated the answer. Now I am handling the file uploading part in a separate function called `handle_file_upload`. I can still upload new file. No problem occurred while passing the file object into separate function.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've not opened the file for writing yet. You can do that like this:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as file:
    file.write('whatever')
```

Comment: Do you mean I should with on the file to be written too? (I. e. Not the bottle file object, but the destination file)

Comment: I've not used the bottle framework, so I cannot comment on that aspect. But the destination file will need opening (with write permissions) as the error you've seen indicates.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the right answer. I'm such an oaf for not realizing that.

Comment: Well, the problem still persists. It seems that that was not the problem.